# What is the mental state called when I forget my thoughts?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, psychology

Suppose I am talking to someone and while talking more thoughts come to my mind that I wish to talk about. I postpone those thoughts, however, to tell everything synchronously, *i.e.*, I wish to tell the old thoughts first and then the new thoughts in sequence. But by the time I finish telling previous thoughts and try to come to those new thoughts that I postponed to tell, some are vanished. This must be a very common phenomenon, as everyone has experienced the dreaded

> ***What on earth was I about to say...?***

What is the term for this mental state, or of the process mentioned?

Comment: I've edited the question in an attempt to generalize it into a topic applicable to the general population.

Comment: Yes I noticed, you have made the situation's description more accurate. Thank you for that.

Comment: Working memory in the process though. But I would suppose also that the issue of interference should not be looked down upon here.

Comment: It's simpy call it "absentmindedness". We're all susceptible to such things and it doesn't neccessarily mean there's anything wrong with our mental processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**
The key term in your question is working memory.

**Background**
**[Working memory](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7143)** is involved in information-processing functions such as encoding, storing, and retrieving data and it is a system that temporarily stored and manages information required to carry out cognitive tasks, such as learning, reasoning, and comprehension.

One relatively straightforward test to assess working memory is **memory span**. In this test the number of items (usually words or numbers) is determined that a person can hold onto and recall. In a typical test of memory span, an examiner reads a list of random numbers aloud at about the rate of one number per second. At the end of a sequence, the person being tested is asked to recall the items in order. The average memory span for normal adults is 7 items (source: [Medicine Net](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7143)).

Note that the definition of [working memory](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7143), as opposed to short-term memory and, to a lesser extent, long-term memory are not that well defined. In fact, [Medicine Net](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7143) links two identical webpages to [short-term memory](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7142) and [working memory](http://www.medicinenet.com/script/main/art.asp?articlekey=7142). The difference between working memory and short-term memory is indeed subtle. Working memory is generally thought to rely on short-term memory, but to additionally involve processes to effectively *use those memories* during cognitive tasks. The difference may be explained as [(Cowen, 2008)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2657600/):

> [W]orking memory includes short-term memory and other processing
>   mechanisms that help to make use of short-term memory.

The difference between short- and long-term memory stores is based on a difference in their *duration* and in their *capacity* [(Cowen, 2008)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2657600/). Long-term memory, not surprisingly, is of longer duration and it can hold much more information. However, it cannot be accessed as readily compared to short-term and working memory.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Cowen, *Prog Brain Res* (2008); **169**: 323–38](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2657600/)</sub>

Comment: So in above dreaded and embarassing situation, short term memory is the one which is not functioning as expected?

Comment: @OsamaMohammedShaikh - I would say working memory, as you are trying not only to remember your topics, but also wish to express them (*i.e.*, *use* them) in an ongoing conversation.